# What is the order of the Crisis on Earth X episodes in the Arrowverse?

Tags: arrowverse, chronology

There seams to be some crossover and I'm unsure of the order of which the episodes are supposed to be watched.

Comment: the order they aired will always work; the titles of the crossover are also numbers part 1/2/3/4.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that the Crisis on Earth X crossover threw the normal episode airing order out of whack.  So if you've been following along since the beginning of the season, know that the episodes resume as normal the following week.  They are only out of whack for crisis on Earth X.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the order to watch those episodes . Crisis on Earth X .

> Supergirl Season 3, Episode 8           (part 1)
>
> Arrow Season 6, Episode 8                  (part 2)
>
> The Flash  Season 4, Episode 8             (part 3)
>
> Legends of Tomorrow  Season 3, Episode 8   (part 4)

Comment: It should be noted, however, that this is NOT the normal watching/airing order of these shows.  The Crisis on Earth X threw things out of whack but I heard that everything will go back to order the following week.